# ISPConfig not working in port 8080 after fresh install in AWS lightsail

Tags: ispconfig, ispconfig-3

Server Details: AWS Lightsail with 4 GB Ram & 2 core
OS Version: Debain 9.12 (stretch)

I have added my static IP 3.6.***.** in DNS records - A, CNAME, TXT, MX, SRV
To set hostname
In AWS once I reboot /etc/hosts file restored to default, So first I edited 
`sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`
and set the parameter "preserve_hostname" from "false" to "true" and then
`sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`

After that I changed  /etc/hostname to `server1` and /etc/hosts to

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
172.26.***.***   server1.mydomain.com   server1   //** Private IP
```

Then I  Reboot the server. I confirmed the hostname status by hostname and hostname -f
Then I followed 100% what is instructed in ISPConfig 3.1: Automated installation on Debian 9 from this forum.

`netstat -tap`
result

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:imaps           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:pop3s           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:10023 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      346/postgrey --pidf
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:10024 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      970/amavisd-new (ma
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:10025 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/master
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:10026 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      970/amavisd-new (ma
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:10027 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:submission      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/master
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:11211 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      490/memcached
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:pop3            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:imap2           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:urd             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ftp             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      965/pure-ftpd (SERV
tcp        0      0 server1.impusese:domain 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      487/named
tcp        0      0 localhost.locald:domain 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      487/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      546/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:smtp            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      942/master
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdoma:953 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      487/named
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:34736 localhost.localdo:mysql ESTABLISHED 1088/amavisd-new (c
tcp        0    272 server1.impuseserve:ssh ***.198.***.79:33698     ESTABLISHED 5367/sshd: admin [p
tcp       61      0 localhost.localdo:46216 localhost.localdo:10025 CLOSE_WAIT  1088/amavisd-new (c
tcp        0    160 server1.impuseserve:ssh ***.198.***.79:33538     ESTABLISHED 4811/sshd: admin [p
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imaps              [::]:*                  LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3s              [::]:*                  LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:10024     [::]:*                  LISTEN      970/amavisd-new (ma
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:10026     [::]:*                  LISTEN      970/amavisd-new (ma
tcp6       0      0 [::]:mysql              [::]:*                  LISTEN      788/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 [::]:submission         [::]:*                  LISTEN      942/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3               [::]:*                  LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imap2              [::]:*                  LISTEN      515/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      663/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN      663/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:urd                [::]:*                  LISTEN      942/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:tproxy             [::]:*                  LISTEN      663/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ftp                [::]:*                  LISTEN      965/pure-ftpd (SERV
tcp6       0      0 [::]:domain             [::]:*                  LISTEN      487/named
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      546/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN      942/master
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:953       [::]:*                  LISTEN      487/named
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN      663/apache2
tcp6       0      0 localhost.localdo:mysql localhost.localdo:34736 ESTABLISHED 788/mysqld
```

`iptables -L`
result

```
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-pureftpd  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ftp
f2b-postfix-sasl  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-postfix-sasl (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-pureftpd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

htf_report.txt

```
##### SERVER #####
IP-address (as per hostname): ***.***.***.***
[WARN] could not determine server's ip address by ifconfig
[INFO] OS version is Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch)

[INFO] ISPConfig is installed.
[WARN] /usr/local/ispconfig/server/lib/config.inc.php is missing.

##### VERSION CHECK #####

[INFO] php (cli) version is 7.0.33-0+deb9u7

##### PORT CHECK #####

##### MAIL SERVER CHECK #####

##### RUNNING SERVER PROCESSES #####

[WARN] I could not determine which web server is running.
[WARN] I could not determine which mail server is running.
[WARN] I could not determine which pop3 server is running.
[WARN] I could not determine which imap server is running.
[WARN] I could not determine which ftp server is running.

##### LISTENING PORTS #####
(only           ()
Local           (Address)
[anywhere]:993          (-)
[anywhere]:995          (-)
[localhost]:10023               (-)
[localhost]:10024               (-)
[localhost]:10025               (-)
[localhost]:10026               (-)
[localhost]:10027               (-)
[anywhere]:587          (-)
[localhost]:11211               (-)
[anywhere]:110          (-)
[anywhere]:143          (-)
[anywhere]:465          (-)
[anywhere]:21           (-)
***.***.***.***:53              (-)
[localhost]:53          (-)
[anywhere]:22           (-)
[anywhere]:25           (-)
[localhost]:953         (-)
*:*:*:*::*:993          (-)
*:*:*:*::*:995          (-)
*:*:*:*::*:10024                (-)
*:*:*:*::*:10026                (-)
*:*:*:*::*:3306         (-)
*:*:*:*::*:587          (-)
[localhost]10           (-)
[localhost]43           (-)
*:*:*:*::*:80           (-)
*:*:*:*::*:8080         (-)
*:*:*:*::*:465          (-)
*:*:*:*::*:8081         (-)
*:*:*:*::*:21           (-)
*:*:*:*::*:53           (-)
*:*:*:*::*:22           (-)
*:*:*:*::*:25           (-)
*:*:*:*::*:953          (-)
*:*:*:*::*:443          (-)

##### IPTABLES #####
```

In my  static IP
`3.6.***.**` << Apache home page loading http:// but not loading in https://
`3.6.***.**` /webmail << roundcube login page loading in http:// but not loading in https://

But ISPConfig 3 is not loading in both https://server1.mydomain.com:8080 and https://myprivateip:8080 << even not working in http://
I am getting error like  ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Need your support to resolve this...

Comment: Did you get any solution regarding this problem.. Please can explain?

Answer (score 1):

In lightsail instance go to Networking > Custom TCP Port 8080 in Firewall.